# how to divide two columns on series with json in highchart

Tags: json, highcharts, series

I have script json like this, i want divide column value_a with total

```
regional value_a    total
SUL      1072       5823
KAL      991        5472
PUMA     253        1832
```

> value_a/total*100

```
series = [{
      borderWidth: 0,
      data: json[2]['total'],
      data: json[1]['value_a'],
      dataLabels: {
        style: {
                fontWeight: "normal"
              },
        formatter: function() {
            var y = this.y;
            var percentage = (this.y/json[2]['total']*100).toFixed(2);
            return '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'white') + '"><br/>'+ y +'</span><span><small> / ' + percentage + ' %</small></span>';
          }
      }
    }];
```

but the result is show NaN

[image]

Comment: please show us the JSON in question. Also what is the value of `this.y` when you do your calculation. It seems likely your division operation is using some invalid values somewhere, hence the result cannot be a valid number

Answer (score 0):

You can create a division formula in your query, to get the results of the division